# ElasticSearch 7 & PHP - Create mapping for parent / child relation

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to index in my index `buildings` 2 types of documents: `building` & `apartment`.

A `building` can have several `apartment`, so I want to use parent/child relationships.

I use ES 7.10 and PHP with official PHP lib (elasticsearch/elasticsearch).

According to the doc (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html), I have to use something like :

```json
PUT index buildings
{
  "mappings": {
    "building": {},
    "apartment": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "building"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my PHP I have :

```php
$this->getClient()->indices()
        ->create([
            'index' => 'buildings',
            'body' => [
                'mappings' => [
                    'building' => [],
                    'apartment' => [
                        '_parent' => [
                            'type' => 'building'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Which throws the error:

> Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [apartment: {_parent={type=building}}] [building: []]"}},"status":400}

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Parent/type has been deprecated in favor of `join` type in Elasticsearch 7 as far as I remember, so this might be the reason you're getting the exception.

Link to docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: Oh yeah... I was reading an old doc, I didn't notice the warning, I will check this new one thanks